# tweety twitter APi returning nothing (python)

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I am using the tweepy and geocode packages to convert ZipCodes to lat and long to then pull from the twitter API using tweepy however I am not getting anything to return. I have gone through and executed my code line by line and get stuck on the api.search every time returning nothing.

```
query = 'stack'
radius = 1000
DataSet = pd.DataFrame
loopCount = 0
appended_data = []
appendData = []

def toDataFrame(tweets):

    DataSet = pd.DataFrame()

    DataSet['tweetID'] = [tweet.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetText'] = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetRetweetCt'] = [tweet.retweet_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetFavoriteCt'] = [tweet.favorite_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetSource'] = [tweet.source for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetCreated'] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userID'] = [tweet.user.id for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userScreen'] = [tweet.user.screen_name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userName'] = [tweet.user.name for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userCreateDt'] = [tweet.user.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userDesc'] = [tweet.user.description for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFollowerCt'] = [tweet.user.followers_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userFriendsCt'] = [tweet.user.friends_count for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userLocation'] = [tweet.user.location for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['userTimezone'] = [tweet.user.time_zone for twee

def location(zip):
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    location = geolocator.geocode(zip)
    cordinates = ((location.latitude, location.longitude))
    cordinates = str(cordinates)
    cordinates = cordinates.replace("(","")
    cordinates = cordinates.replace(")","")
    return cordinates

def lookUp(results):
    for result in results:
        DataSet = pd.DataFrame(results)
        print DataSet
        return DataSet

##hidden for SO
auth = tp.OAuthHandler('','')
auth.set_access_token('', '')

api = tp.API(auth)

for zip in zips:
#for row, zip in zips.iterrows():
    if (loopCount == 15):
        t.sleep(960)
        loopCount = 0
    loopCount = loopCount + 1
    cordinates = location(zip)
    inputCode = cordinates + ', ' + str(radius)
    results = api.search(geocode=inputCode, count=100, q=query)
    DataSet = lookUp(results)
    appendData.append(DataSet)
appended_data = pd.concat(appendedData, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful not to pass spaces in the `geocode`, and also add the units. For example, using your function `location`,

```
In [5]:
zip = 28039
cordinates = location(zip)

In [23]:
radius = '1km'
inputCode = cordinates + ', ' + str(radius)
inputCode = inputCode.replace(' ', '')
inputCode

Out[23]:
'40.4604043354592,-3.70401484102134,1km'

In [24]:
query = 'a'
results = api.search(geocode=inputCode, count=100, q=query)

In [25]:
len(results)
Out[25]:
100
```

Reference [twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets):

> The parameter value is specified by “latitude,longitude,radius”, where
>   radius units must be specified as either “mi” (miles) or “km”
>   (kilometers).

Hope it helps.